# Multipart form of a single form in Yii

Tags: php, database, yii

Suppose in Yii Framework I have the attributes for the model like this

```
  field_1
  field_2
  field_3
  field_4
  field_5
  field_6
  field_7
  field_8
  field_9
  field_10
```

Now as I am saving the form of this models then all the attributes are doing validation and save in a single form. But I want all the models to make validation and save part by part.Just like this

```
  field_1
  field_2
  field_3
  field_4
```

These should come in a single form and should be validate and save in the database.After that

```
  field_5
  field_6
  field_7
  field_8
```

These should also come in a single form and should be validate and save in the database.After that

```
  field_9
  field_10
```

At the end this should also come in a single form and should be validate and save in the database.So how to do that.I searched the total yii documentation but not got any good result.Any help and suggestions will be highly appriciable.

Comment: searching for **multi page forms**, will get you some help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can also be solved by using scenarios. Look them up in the Yii documentation.